# Values from multiple tables on a row

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following 3 tables

```
Table1

ID |   NAME
-----------
1  | X
2  | Y
3  | Z


Table2

ID |   NAME
-----------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C

Table3
ID | P (Boolean field)  | Other cols
 1 | True ...
 2 | True....
 1 | False
```

Now I need a query on table3 that has to do the following:

To display the name field of table1 and table2. But my problem is that
if field P on table3 is true I want it to display the name of table2's field where table2.id = table3.id but if it is false I need it to read the name of table1's name field where table1.id = table3.id.

The program which will display the results is a desktop application and i could do it with some procedure or something to display them, but would be nicer if I had a SQL query to do this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN p
        THEN
        (
        SELECT  name
        FROM    table2 t2
        WHERE   t2.id = t3.id
        ) 
        ELSE
        (
        SELECT  name
        FROM    table1 t1
        WHERE   t1.id = t3.id
        )
        END
FROM    table3 t3
```

, or this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN p THEN t2.name ELSE t1.name END
FROM    table3 t3
JOIN    table1 t1
ON      t1.id = t3.id
JOIN    table1 t2
ON      t2.id = t3.id
```

In systems capable of doing `HASH JOIN` (that is `Oracle`, `SQL Server`, `PostgreSQL`, but not `MySQL`), the second one is better if the boolean values are distributed evenly, i. e. there are lots of both `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s, and if `table3` is quite large.

The first one is better if there is a skew in distribution, if there are much fewer rows in `table3` then in `table1` or `table2`, or if you are using `MySQL`.

**Update:**

If the majority of fields are false, the following query will probably be the best:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN p THEN
        (
        SELECT  name
        FROM    table2 t2
        WHERE   t2.id = t3.id
        )
        ELSE t1.name
        END AS cname
FROM    table3 t3
JOIN    table1 t1
ON      t1.id = t3.id
ORDER BY
        cname
```

Subquery here will only be used as a fallback, and will be executed only for the rare `TRUE` values.

**Update 2:**

I can't check it on Firebird, but on most systems the `ORDER BY` syntax as in query above will work. If it does not, wrap the query into an inline view:

```
SELECT  cname
FROM    (
        SELECT  CASE WHEN p THEN
                (
                SELECT  name
                FROM    table2 t2
                WHERE   t2.id = t3.id
                )
                ELSE t1.name
                END AS cname
        FROM    table3 t3
        JOIN    table1 t1
        ON      t1.id = t3.id
        ) q
ORDER BY
        cname
```

, though it may hamper performance (at least in `MySQL` it does).

Comment: The majority will be having that field False, so seems that the first one will suit me better

Comment: You may then join with `table2` (which names the false values) and use `table1` in a subquery as a fallback.

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm, but there's a last thing where i could use your help. Is there any way to sort the data by the "name" column in the case statement?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
select if(P, t1.name, t2.name) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, IF(`table3`.`P`, `table2`.`name`, `table1`.`name`) AS `name`
FROM `table3`
JOIN `table2` USING (`id`)
JOIN `table1` USING (`id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not an option but sometimes a schema redesign will solve a lot of problems. Any solution that executes per-row functions should be examined *very* carefully for performance problems (actually *any* query should be continuously monitored for performance problems but especially per-row function ones).

Consider combining tables 1 and 2 together thus:

```
Table1And2:
    Id | IsTable2 | Name
    ---+----------+-----
    1  | false    | X
    2  | false    | Y
    3  | false    | Z
    1  | true     | A
    2  | true     | B
    3  | true     | C
    Primary key (Id,IsTable2)
    Possible index on (IsTable2) as well, depending on DBMS.

Table3:
    Id | P (Boolean field)  | OtherCols
    ---+--------------------+----------
     1 | true               |
     2 | true               |
     1 | false              |
```

Then your query becomes a relatively simple (and almost certainly blindingly fast):

```
select a.Id, b.Name, a.OtherCols
from Table3 a, Table1And2 b
where a.Id = b.Id and a.P = b.isTable2
```

The performance issue usually only rears its head for large tables, mainframe sizes where 5 million rows is considered a configuration table :-) It may not be necessary for the sort of tables you're dealing with but it's a useful tool to have in the armory.

Comment: That can't be done as table2 references rows from table1 (foreign keys, one or two queries on table1 for "computed by" rows)
also they have different structure on the other columns.

Comment: Well, technically you can have foreign keys referencing the same table and the different structures could be separated to even more tables :-) But at some point (and it's probably at that point right there), schema redesigns become more trouble than they're worth - you should probably go for one of the per-row-function answers and just make sure their performance is good enough for your table size (likely unless you're tables are massive).

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this query in mysql.

```
        SELECT T3.ID,
               T3.P,
               IF(T3.P = true,  T2.NAME, T1.NAME) AS NAME
        FROM Table3 T3
        LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
        LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
```